# Is there any relevance of diet on learning?

Tags: learning

I'm curious about the current research and literature on the effects of diet on learning. Cause myelin is supposed important for myelination, which is relevant for learning according to "The Talent Code" by Daniel Coyle and myelination requires a diet of fats, which I read somewhere once. So I was wondering what nutrients and diet help learning if any?

Comment: Similar to [How can motivation be increased by improving brain chemistry with nutrition and activities?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/1755/7001)